# Get A List of all files's url from a Website Directory in Iphone / IOS and store them in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I Want to list all the file's urls. Files are present on a website. They are in a public directory in a website. No Ftp access is required to access the urls. So no ftp based programming is needed.

For example- www.mysite.com/myimages/(multiple files)

I want to store All the files URL path in NSMutableArray. Can anybody assist me or explain me the proper way to do this in iphone using objective c.

Hope to Get a Solution,
Thank You,
Tuhin Bhatt

Answer (score 0):

I think below approach will be one to solve the problem.

You have to make a simple web-service api that will simple return the all url links in json / xml format. Then you parse the response and store those in a NSMutableArray